# Does Android cache Database Views?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, view

I have had a defect reported in one of my apps, the log file says "no column with name abc".  This column was recently changed from abc to xyz, and if the user clears their application data (causing the db to be reinstalled) then the issue goes away.

It's looking to me like the db schema was correctly updated, but the updated view was not applied (as the only possible reference to abc is in a view).  The schema update is performed by copying a new db rather than running alter table etc so I know the view must have been updated if the ddl was.

This leaves me thinking that Android might be pre-compiling and caching views - does anyone know if this is the case?  And if so, can the cache be cleared via code?  I've searched but so far have been unable to find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of views are not cached separately, and not persistently (the page cache is part of the connection and gets dropped when the database is closed).

The only possible explanations are that the update was applied partially (how do you handle errors in the middle of the copying?), or that there is still some reference to `abc` in the app.

Comment: I've double checked the code and there are no references to abc except in the view, which is part of the db which is copied.  Did find a similar question where the schema was changed and appeared to be 'cached' but there was no resolution - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743045/android-database-strangeness-listing-columns)