# Cursor returns the same columns after "Query, Drop Table, Create Table, Query for the same table name"

Tags: android, sqlite

For example I have a table named `myTable` in my database file (Android, p.s. it doesn't support column renaming, deleting and so on).

This table has `idx`, `name` columns

I want to delete and recreate this table but with new columns

Here how I do it:

```
db.transaction {
    var cursor = query("myTable", null, null, null, null, null, null)
    // save info to a list and insert it later to a recreated table with new columns
    cursor.close()

    // delete table "myTable"
    execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS myTable")

    // create table "myTable" but with new columns
    execSQL("CREATE TABLE myTable(id, title)")

    // get columns
    cursor = query("myTable", null, null, null, null, null, null)
    val columnNames = cursor.columnNames
    cursor.close()
    Log.i(TAG, "columns of new table ${Arrays.toString(columnNames)}")
}
```

But `cursor.columnNames` doesn't return new columns (`id`, `title`)

It returns the old columns (e.g., `idx`, `name`)

Though when I close the app and open again everything is ok (old columns are gone and new ones are available)

So annoying!

So new columns are created ok in `main.db/myTable` during all this process but seems the app still keeps old columns in memory

I can't even use `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title"))` (would return `-1`) because it still thinks that this column doesn't exist yet until I restart this app

BUT! Recreating a table with new columns works fine if I don't use `cursor` to backup data (info) before I delete the old table

```
db.transaction {
    // !! I COMMENTED THESE LINES
    // var cursor = query("myTable", null, null, null, null, null, null)
    // save info to a list and insert it later to a recreated table with new columns
    // cursor.close()

    // delete table "myTable"
    execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS myTable")

    // create table "myTable" but with new columns
    execSQL("CREATE TABLE myTable(id, title)")

    // get columns
    cursor = query("myTable", null, null, null, null, null, null)
    val columnNames = cursor.columnNames
    cursor.close()
    Log.i(TAG, "columns of new table ${Arrays.toString(columnNames)}")
}
```

In this case `cursor.columnNames` returns new columns `id`, `title`

This is crazy!

So it seems `query table1`, `drop table1`, `create table1`, `query table1` sequence would lead to an unexpected behavior

And we can only do `drop table1`, `create table1`, `query table1` sequence

Comment: `I want to delete and recreate this table but with new columns` ... which **won't work** until you change the **database version**. Why don't you use`ALTER TABLE`, instead?

Comment: @Fantômas well... I do it in `onUpgrade` so of course it's a new version... What are you trying to say? `ALTER TABLE` - what you mean? It's limited in SQLite and there is no support for column renaming. Better try it yourself to understand the issue. It's really a bug. Here's the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743045/android-database-strangeness-listing-columns?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Fantômas also I could just use `INSERT INTO` to copy data (in this case I don't need cursor) but I need to process this data before I send it to a recreated table so I need to cursor anyway. But it should not matter what I need because it seems there is a bug and we have to do something about it

Comment: Don't you want to rename and/or add columns? It seems that `ALTER TABLE` is you best friend, then. https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html

Comment: @Fantômas don't you want to read this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52346199/4548520 I need to support Android 14-28, not 33 (which isn't even here yet)

Comment: I see. Then it's Android not implementing the latest SQLite incarnation. But don't ll the answers in that post help even a bit?

Comment: @Fantômas of course some answers helped but I had to use a new name for table. So I recreated a table with new name (it's not a big deal). But this question is still should be seen by Android team

Comment: Well, yes,it actually sould. But there's nothing WE, as a mutual help community, can do. Other than finding some workarounds (as you did), until the issue is fixed by the Android development team.