# Android SQLite copy table to another table

Tags: android, sqlite, copying, database-table

I want to implement delete column in Android's SQLite. I want to make table copy without desired column, than delete former tablet and set name at new_one as a former name. I have made table to table copy, but now I have it as a 1:1 copy. How to change columns when copyiing?

Goal is to have method **deleteColumn(int indexOfColumn)**;

Thanks

Comment: This answer gives a very good explanation of how this can be achieved.
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424156/upgrade-sqlite-database-from-one-version-to-another/3424444#3424444

Answer (score 15, accepted):

drop your new table first,then create a new table directly with desired columns as follows:

```
create table new_table as select column1,column2,....from old_table;
```

Here select those columns that you want to see in new table.Then drop old table and rename new table to old table's name.Hope it will work.

Comment: You can also use "CREATE TABLE new_table AS SELECT * FROM old_table" to copy the entire structure. This works on iPhone, not tested on Android.

Comment: @ckimbrell it is common sql and so it will work for every platform i think.

Comment: works for android too @ckimbrell