# How to get a table from SQLite DataBase stored in external memory

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am working with DB in android. my db has three tables and i want to get a single table from them.Now I am reading my sqlite file success fully and writing into my desired place to some modification. but issue is that I do not know how to get a single table from database.db file. now i am getting db by using this program.

```
   public void getDB(){
        File f=new File("/data/data/com.android.lunchernewone/databases/launcher.db");
        FileInputStream fis=null;
        FileOutputStream fos=null;

        try
        {
            fis=new FileInputStream(f);
            fos=new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/db_dump.db");
            while(true)
            {
                int i=fis.read();
                if(i!=-1)
                {fos.write(i);}
                else
                {break;}
            }
            fos.flush();
            Toast.makeText(this, "DB dump OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "DB dump ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                fos.close();
                fis.close();
            }
            catch(IOException ioe)
            {}
        }
    }
```

can anybody tell me that how I get a single table from this db file?

Comment: I have a suggestion, i'm not very sure it's the best but it's something to consider. You have 3 tables. Inside your DB handler class, you could have a method that queries the database for the single table and returns whatever it is you want. Then all you have to do is call from this method what you want to do with the data. data could be an arraylist of table contents or even serialized JSON using GSON. Jus keep an open mind on this.

Comment: This copies a table into a new one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2361961/2649012

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this,

create table new_table as select column1,column2,....from old_table;

please look into the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993809/android-sqlite-copy-table-to-another-table)