# Android SQLite database and app update

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-sqlite

I have developed an android app and released version 1.0. The app contains SQLite local database with 5 tables.

Now we planned to release version 2.0 also update the version 1.0 users. In version 2.0 we have included extra two tables with previous 5 table, so 7 tables now.

Now my question is, The version 1.0 users all have some data in the local database, If he update to the version 2.0 the previous data will get lost? If it so. then what is the alternate method?

Comment: if you change the DB architecture, the old DB cannot stay

Comment: @thepoosh Thank you for your reply. If I didn't change the DB architecture, but updated the version with new feature. In that case?

Comment: try reading this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8627242/1056359

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should put all changes in your onUpgrade method you can use this code:

```
@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    String sql = "ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_SECRET + " ADD COLUMN " +
     "name_of_column_to_be_added" + " INTEGER";
    db.execSQL(sql);        
}
```

this adds a column in your current database. Your database will not lose data. Reminder: onUpgrade will be called when getWriteableDatabase or getReadableDatabase is executed AND the version of your database is different from your older version.

Comment: Just to clarify, TABLE_SECRET is the table name.

Answer (score 2):

Change your db version and add extra two table creation methods in your `onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVesion)` method. Now the the previous data will not get lost.

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do some  on `SQLiteOpenHelper#onUpgrade`, get some old data. and insert into new table