# i've published android app, now i want to update my database content and then publish the new version in google play

Tags: android, database, performance, sqlite

I've published android app, now I want to update my database content and then publish the new version in google play.

here is sample of my database class:

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;


    public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 20;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ecovas";
    private Context myContext;
    //Series Table Name
    private static final String TABLE_SERIES = "series";
    private static final String TABLE_EPISODE = "episode";
    private static final String TABLE_SERVICES = "services";
    private static final String TABLE_SENT_SERVICES = "requested_services";

    //Series Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_SID = "sid";
    private static final String KEY_SNAME = "sname";
    private static final String KEY_SIMG = "simg";
    private static final String KEY_SSTATUS = "sstatus";
    private static final String KEY_STAMP = "sStamp";
    //Episdoe Table Columns name 
    private static final String KEY_EPISODE_ID = "episod_id";
    private static final String KEY_EPISODE_NAME = "episode_name";
    private static final String KEY_EPISODE_IMG = "episode_img";
    private static final String KEY_EPISODE_STATUS = "episode_status";
    private static final String KEY_SERIES_ID = "series_id";
    private static final String KEY_EPISODE_VIDEO = "episode_video";
    private static final String KEY_EPISODE_STAMP = "episode_stamp";
    //Services Table Columns name
    private static final String KEY_SERVICE = "id";
    private static final String KEY_SERVICE_ID = "service_id";
    private static final String KEY_SERVICE_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_SERVICE_SHORTCODE = "shortcode";
    private static final String KEY_SERVICE_COMMAND = "command";
    private static final String KEY_SERVICE_MESSAGE_DESCRIPTION = "msg_desc";
    private static final String KEY_SERVICE_STAMP = "service_stamp";
    private static final String KEY_SERVICE_STATUS = "status";
    //requested services table column
    private static final String KEY_R_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_R_SERVICE_ID = "service_r_id";
    private static final String KEY_R_OPERATOR_NAME = "op_name";
    private static final String KEY_R_STAMP = "r_stamp";
    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_SERIES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SERIES + "("
                + KEY_SID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_SNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                + KEY_SIMG + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_SSTATUS + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " + 
                KEY_STAMP + " DATETIME " + ")";
        String CREATE_EPISODE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_EPISODE + "("
                + KEY_EPISODE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_EPISODE_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                + KEY_EPISODE_IMG + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_EPISODE_STATUS + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " 
                + KEY_SERIES_ID + " TEXT NOT NULL, " 
                + KEY_EPISODE_VIDEO + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_EPISODE_STAMP + " DATETIME " + ")";
        String CREATE_SERVICES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SERVICES + "("
                + KEY_SERVICE + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + KEY_SERVICE_ID + " TEXT NOT NULL , " 
                + KEY_SERVICE_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " 
                + KEY_SERVICE_SHORTCODE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_SERVICE_COMMAND + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_SERVICE_MESSAGE_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT NOT NULL, " 
                + KEY_SERVICE_STAMP + " TEXT NOT NULL, " 
                + KEY_SERVICE_STATUS + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0"  + ")";
        String CREATE_REQUSTED_SERVICES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SENT_SERVICES + "("
                + KEY_R_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " 
                + KEY_R_SERVICE_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_R_OPERATOR_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_R_STAMP + " DATETIME " + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_SERIES_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_EPISODE_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_SERVICES_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_REQUSTED_SERVICES_TABLE);
    }
  //getDateTime
    public String getDateTime(){
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                                        Locale.getDefault());
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }
    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed

        if(newVersion == 20){
            Log.e("Upgrade database worked", "working on");
            try{
                String destPath = "/data/data/com.ecovas.cartoony/databases";
                File f = new File(destPath);
                if(!f.exists()){
                    f.mkdirs();
                    f.createNewFile();
                    //copy the db from the assets folder into the database folder
                    CopyDB(myContext.getAssets().open("ecovas"), new FileOutputStream(destPath + "/ecovas"));
                }else{
                    CopyDB(myContext.getAssets().open("ecovas"), new FileOutputStream(destPath + "/ecovas"));
                }
            }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Log.e("newVersion : ", ""+newVersion);
        Log.e("oldVersion : ", ""+oldVersion);
        if(newVersion > oldVersion){
            try{
                String destPath = "/data/data/com.ecovas.cartoony/databases";
                File f = new File(destPath);
                if(!f.exists()){
                    f.mkdirs();
                    f.createNewFile();
                    //copy the db from the assets folder into the database folder
                    CopyDB(myContext.getAssets().open("ecovas"), new FileOutputStream(destPath + "/ecovas"));
                }else{
                    CopyDB(myContext.getAssets().open("ecovas"), new FileOutputStream(destPath + "/ecovas"));
                }
            }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
     */


    void addSeries(SeriesCls s){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues v = new ContentValues();
        v.put(KEY_SNAME, s.getName());
        v.put(KEY_SIMG, s.getSIMG());
        v.put(KEY_SSTATUS, s.getSStatus());
        v.put(KEY_STAMP, getDateTime());
        db.insert(TABLE_SERIES, null, v);
    }
    void addServices(ServicesCls services){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues v = new ContentValues();
        v.put(KEY_SERVICE_ID, services.getServiceId());
        v.put(KEY_SERVICE_NAME, services.getServiceName());
        v.put(KEY_SERVICE_SHORTCODE, services.getShortCode());
        v.put(KEY_SERVICE_COMMAND, services.getCommand());
        v.put(KEY_SERVICE_MESSAGE_DESCRIPTION, services.getMesg());
        v.put(KEY_SERVICE_STAMP, getDateTime());
        v.put(KEY_SERVICE_STATUS, services.getStatus());
        db.insert(TABLE_SERVICES, null, v);
    }
    void addRequstedServices(int r_s_id, String op_name){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues v = new ContentValues();
        v.put(KEY_R_SERVICE_ID, r_s_id);
        v.put(KEY_R_OPERATOR_NAME, op_name);
        v.put(KEY_R_STAMP, getDateTime());
        db.insert(TABLE_SENT_SERVICES, null, v);
    }

    void addEpisode(EpisodeCls e){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues v = new ContentValues();
        v.put(KEY_EPISODE_NAME, e.getName());
        v.put(KEY_EPISODE_IMG, e.getIMG());
        v.put(KEY_EPISODE_STATUS, e.getStatus());
        v.put(KEY_SERIES_ID, e.getSid());
        v.put(KEY_EPISODE_VIDEO, e.getVideo());
        v.put(KEY_EPISODE_STAMP, getDateTime());
        db.insert(TABLE_EPISODE, null, v);
    }

    public List<ServicesCls> getAllServices(){
        List<ServicesCls> serviceList = new ArrayList<ServicesCls>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_SERVICES;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                ServicesCls services = new ServicesCls();
                services.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                services.setServiceId(cursor.getString(1));
                services.setServiceName(cursor.getString(2));
                services.setShortCode(cursor.getString(3));
                services.setCommand(cursor.getString(4));
                services.setMesg(cursor.getString(5));
                //services.setDate(cursor.getString(6));
                services.setStatus(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(7)));
                serviceList.add(services);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        return serviceList;
    }
    public List<SeriesCls> getAllSS() {
        List<SeriesCls> contactList = new ArrayList<SeriesCls>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SERIES + " ORDER BY sid DESC;";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                SeriesCls s = new SeriesCls();
                s.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                s.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                s.setSIMG(cursor.getString(2));
                s.setSStatus(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)));
                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(s);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // return contact list
        cursor.close();
        return contactList;
    }
    /*List<ServicesCls> getAllServicesOld(){
        //SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        List<ServicesCls> servicesList = new ArrayList<ServicesCls>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SERVICES + " LIMIT 1";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                ServicesCls s = new ServicesCls();
                s.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                s.setServiceName(cursor.getString(1));
                s.setShortCode(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
                s.setCommand(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)));
                s.setMesg(cursor.getString(4));
                // Adding contact to list
                servicesList.add(s);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // return contact list
        cursor.close();
        return servicesList;
    }*/
    List<RequestedServicesCls> getRServices(){
        List<RequestedServicesCls> contactList = new ArrayList<RequestedServicesCls>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SENT_SERVICES;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                RequestedServicesCls s = new RequestedServicesCls();
                s.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                s.setServiceID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
                s.setOP(cursor.getString(2));
                //s.setSStatus(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)));
                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(s);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // return contact list
        cursor.close();
        return contactList;
    }
    //join services table with requested services table
    /*List<String> getJoinsServices(){
        //Create new querybuilder
        SQLiteQueryBuilder _QB = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        _QB.setTables(TABLE_SERVICES + " INNER JOIN " +
                TABLE_SENT_SERVICES + " ON " +
                KEY_SERVICE_ID + " = " + KEY_R_SERVICE_ID);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        List<String> join = new ArrayList<String>();
        //String query = "SELECT a.service_id, b.service_id, b.op_name FROM services a INNER JOIN requested_services b ON a.service_id=b.service_id ;";
        Cursor cursor = _QB.query(db, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                RequestedServicesCls s = new RequestedServicesCls();
                ServicesCls service = new ServicesCls();
                service.setServiceId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_SERVICE_ID)));
                s.setServiceID(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_R_SERVICE_ID)));
                s.setOP(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_R_OPERATOR_NAME)));
                //s.setSStatus(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)));
                String x = String.valueOf(service.getServiceId());
                String y = String.valueOf(s.getServiceId());
                String z = s.getOP();
                // Adding contact to list
                //String s_id = String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_SERVICE_ID)));
                //String s_r_id = String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_R_SERVICE_ID)));
                //String s_r_op = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_R_OPERATOR_NAME));
                join.add(x);
                join.add(y);
                join.add(z);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }else{
            join.add(null);
        }
        // return contact list
        cursor.close();
        return join;
    }*/
    /*List<ServicesCls> getServiceLimit(int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        List<ServicesCls> episodeList = new ArrayList<ServicesCls>();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(false, TABLE_SERVICES, new String[] {KEY_SERVICE ,KEY_SERVICE_ID,
                KEY_SERVICE_NAME, KEY_SERVICE_SHORTCODE, KEY_SERVICE_COMMAND, KEY_SERVICE_MESSAGE_DESCRIPTION},
                KEY_SERVICE + " =? ",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null,null, null, "1");
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                ServicesCls s = new ServicesCls();
                s.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                s.setServiceId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
                s.setServiceName(cursor.getString(2));
                s.setShortCode(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)));
                s.setCommand(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(4)));
                s.setMesg(cursor.getString(5));
                // Adding contact to list
                episodeList.add(s);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        return episodeList;
    }*/
    List<EpisodeCls> getE(Object id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        List<EpisodeCls> episodeList = new ArrayList<EpisodeCls>();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_EPISODE, new String[] { KEY_EPISODE_ID,
                KEY_EPISODE_NAME, KEY_EPISODE_IMG, KEY_EPISODE_STATUS, KEY_SERIES_ID, KEY_EPISODE_VIDEO },
                KEY_SERIES_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                EpisodeCls e = new EpisodeCls();
                e.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                e.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                e.setIMG(cursor.getString(2));
                e.setStatus(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)));
                e.setSid(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(4)));
                e.setVideo(cursor.getString(5));
                // Adding contact to list
                episodeList.add(e);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        return episodeList;
    }
    public List<EpisodeCls> getAllEE(Object id) {
        List<EpisodeCls> epoList = new ArrayList<EpisodeCls>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_EPISODE 
       + " WHERE " + KEY_SERIES_ID + " = " + String.valueOf(id);

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                EpisodeCls e = new EpisodeCls();
                e.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                e.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                e.setIMG(cursor.getString(2));
                e.setStatus(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)));
                e.setSid(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(4)));
                e.setVideo(cursor.getString(5));
                // Adding contact to list
                epoList.add(e);
                // Adding contact to list
                epoList.add(e);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // return contact list
        cursor.close();
        return epoList;
    }


    public void deleteSS(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_SERIES, KEY_SID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
        db.close();
    }

    public void deleteE(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_EPISODE, KEY_EPISODE_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
        db.close();
    }
    public void deleteAllServices(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_SERVICES, null, null);
        db.close();
    }
    public int getSeriesVount(){
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SERIES;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        //cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }
    public int getEpisodeCount(){
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_EPISODE;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }
    public boolean isMatch(String serviceId){
        //boolean value = false;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        //Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_SERVICES, new String[] {KEY_SERVICE, KEY_SERVICE_ID},
            //  KEY_SERVICE + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(serviceId)}, null, null,null);
        Cursor c = db.query(false, TABLE_SERVICES, new String[] {KEY_SERVICE ,KEY_SERVICE_ID,
                KEY_SERVICE_NAME, KEY_SERVICE_SHORTCODE, KEY_SERVICE_COMMAND, KEY_SERVICE_MESSAGE_DESCRIPTION},
                KEY_SERVICE_ID + " =? ",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(serviceId) }, null,null, null, null);
        if(c.getCount() > 0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
        //if(c.moveToFirst()){
            //while(c.moveToNext()){
                //value=true;
            //}
        //}else{
            //value=false;
        //}

        //Log.e("Matched Service is ", service_id);
        //return value;
    }
    public String getVideo(Object id){
        String Video_id;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_EPISODE, new String[] { KEY_EPISODE_ID,
                KEY_EPISODE_NAME, KEY_EPISODE_IMG, KEY_EPISODE_STATUS, KEY_SERIES_ID, KEY_EPISODE_VIDEO },
                KEY_EPISODE_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        //String q = "SELECT " + KEY_EPISODE_VIDEO + " FROM " + TABLE_EPISODE + " WHERE " + KEY_EPISODE_VIDEO + " = "
        //+ String.valueOf(id);
        //Cursor c = db.rawQuery(q, null);
        if(cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        EpisodeCls e = new EpisodeCls();
        e.setVideo(cursor.getString(5));
        Video_id = e.getVideo();
        Log.e("Video Id : ", Video_id);
        return Video_id;
    }
    private void CopyDB(InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws IOException{
        //copy 1K bytes at a time
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0){
            os.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        is.close();
        os.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890774/android-sqlite-database-and-app-update

Comment: You already have `onUpgrade` method implemented. What's the problem?

Comment: when i upload the new version on google play, the app did not update the content.

Comment: check my answer, and make sure you have got those things right. Now once you publish it, you need to give the store some time, 2-3hours and check the app for updates again

Comment: i've tried that and i understand that, but when i update the app suppose the application update the database too, in my case the database did not update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the cue from question:
"now I want to update my database content and then publish the new version in google play."

*now I want to update my database content*  : This part doesn't seem to be a problem actually(?)

For *then publish the new version in google play.*

Check your manifest for

### android:versionCode

> An internal version number. This number is used only to determine whether one version is more recent than another, with higher numbers indicating more recent versions. This is not the version number shown to users; that number is set by the versionName attribute.
>   The value must be set as an integer, such as "100". You can define it however you want, as long as each successive version has a higher number.

Source:  [Android manifest elements](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html)

Refer: [Versioning Apps](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html)

Now update your code for the application with the new database content, then update the `versionCode` accordingly and publish the new apk on playstore.

It will replace the existing one and user's will be updated with respect to that and their preferences of receiving updates.
Ref: [Updating your app](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en)

It should be signed with the same keystore, as the one which is already on Play Store.

You can use `versionName` to identify if the updated app has reached the store and your mobile or not:

### android:versionName

> The version number shown to users. This attribute can be set as a raw string or as a reference to a string resource. The string has no other purpose than to be displayed to users. The versionCode attribute holds the significant version number used internally.

`versionName` is just something that's shown to the user

Answer (score 1):

1.Change the DATABASE_VERSION like(it is 20 change it to 21).

2.if you add some new column into table than use query on onupgrade method.

```
 if (newVersion > oldVersion) {

                        UpdateReservedTable(db);
                    } 

public static void UpdateReservedTable(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        List<String> columnlist = new ArrayList<String>();
        //db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        columnlist = GetColumns(db, RESERVED_TABLE);
        if (!columnlist.contains(Reserved.DROP_OFF_BETWEEN)) {

            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + RESERVED_TABLE + " ADD COLUMN "
                    + Reserved.DROP_OFF_BETWEEN + " VARCHAR");
        }
        if (!columnlist.contains(Reserved.PICK_UP_TIME)) {
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + RESERVED_TABLE + " ADD COLUMN "
                    + Reserved.PICK_UP_TIME + " VARCHAR");
        }
    }
```