# Uninstalling an app from the device is not removing database

Tags: android

I'm facing some issue with app uninstall from the device. The related database seems to not being deleted so I'm unable to update my table and add new column.
What can be the problem.

Android version is 6.0.

Comment: You can update the whole database by the following link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133597/android-upgrading-db-version-and-adding-new-table

Comment: So one more question. Can I return back to the version 1 after testing done?

Comment: I think you can't, but I'm not tested.
You can keep increase the version.

Answer (score 3):

To remove the database when the app uninstall in android6...
Adds in the AndroidManifest the follow tags:

```
<application 
    android:allowBackup="false" 
    tools:replace="android:allowBackup">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want any update reflects in ur existing database , then no need to delete or drop it manually . sqlite provides **onUpgrade()** for that . you can find lots of good stackoverflow solution ,just google on it how **onUpgrade()** used .

you can use that like this way ,

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    switch(oldVersion){
        case 1:
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ADD COLUMN " + NEW_COLUMN_NAME + TYPE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling only removes the files in `data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE`.

If you are adding `.db` object by your own, (so do not implement `Content Provider`) and put the db object another directory it wont be deleted.

Also you can use `onUpgrade()` method.

Comment: No, I'm not putting it to any directory