# How android app update work for databse based applications?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Hello guys I just launched my application on playstore, I have ship my sqlite database with app which is assets folder then I copy that database in app/data folder and my application is work on it.

Now my question is in My new version of app I add new table in database.
So I want to replace existing database of user which running an old version of
database.

I don't know how exactly app update process work.

after update old copy of database is replaced ?
or I specifically write a method that check
if there is existing old copy of database is available
so replaced it with new database.

Comment: Are you using any kind of ORM? Like GreenDao or OrmLite?

Comment: No. Its simple database file, having 2 tables. In new version I am adding 3 extra tables.

Comment: visit the link i shared

Comment: You should have uses [SQLiteAssetHelper](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-sqlite-asset-helper/).

Answer (score 0):

To know everything good about how to update database on app update is given right here : [Android: upgrading DB version and adding new table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133597/android-upgrading-db-version-and-adding-new-table)

Hope it will help :)

Comment: Thanks for your link, can you tell me how exactly update process works

Comment: I don't know How down vote happened, (it may happened while checking replay on staoverflow app ) anyway i corrected it. :) :) :)