# Android - Sqlite - Detect if new version not found

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

Updated: Bref: The answer of Kuffs is simple and correct. The answer of MikeT is a interesting approach.

Old version:
I'm working on an android app.
I need to know if there are a new sql version or not. If my db is up to date, I will trigger an async action.
But how can I trigger my async action?

Currently, I have my own flag `onNewVersion` who is set to `true` in `onUpgrade()`. Then I do the check in `onOpen()`. Are there any other methods?

```
@override
onUpgrade(...) {
    onNewVersion = true;
    ...
}

@override
onOpen(...) {
    if (onNewVersion == FALSE)
        triggerAction();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: This my help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133597/android-upgrading-db-version-and-adding-new-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are there any other methods?

Yes, I personally use a sort of pseudo/wanted/desired schema and in short compare this against what actually exists columns, tables, indexes being created(tables indexes)/added(columns) as required.

As such I don't use versions and `onUpgrade` is empty.

for example these are the core methods in my SQLiteOpenhelper subclass :-

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        usable = this.onExpand(db,false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldversion, int newversion) {
    }

    public boolean onExpand(SQLiteDatabase db, boolean buildandexpand) {
        boolean rv = true;
        if (db == null) {
            db = instance.getWritableDatabase();
        }
        // Is the Database definition valid to use?
        if (DBConstants.cardonsier.isDBDatabaseUsable()) {
            ArrayList<String> buildsql = DBConstants.cardonsier.generateDBBuildSQL(db);
            // Anything to build
            if (!buildsql.isEmpty()) {
                // YES so build the Database
                DBConstants.cardonsier.actionDBBuildSQL(db);
            }
            if (buildandexpand) {
                ArrayList<String> altersql = DBConstants.cardonsier.generateDBAlterSQL(db);
                if (!altersql.isEmpty()) {
                    DBConstants.cardonsier.actionDBAlterSQL(db);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            rv = false;
        }
        return rv;
    }
```

DBConstants.cardoniser refers to the DBDatabase object defined as :-

```
    static final DBDatabase cardonsier = new DBDatabase(DATABASENAME,
            new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                    DBCardsTableConstants.CARDS,
                    DBUsertableConstants.USERS,
                    DBCardUserLinkTableConstants.CARDUSERLINKS,
                    DBPreftableConstants.PREFS,
                    DBPayeestableContants.PAYEES,
                    DBCategoriestableConstants.CATEGORIES,
                    DBCardCategoryLinkTableConstants.CARDCATEGORYLINKS,
                    DBCardPayeeLinkTableConstants.CARDPAYEELINKS,
                    DBTransactionsTableConstants.TRANSACTIONS,
                    DBCardTypesTableConstants.CARDTYPES
            ))
    );
```

i.e. the list of DBTable objects, they including DBColumn objects e.g :-

```
static final DBTable CARDS = new DBTable(CARDS_TABLE,
        new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                CARDID,
                CARDOWNER,
                CARDNAME,
                CARDTYPEREF,
                CARDNUMBER,
                CARDCVVCODE,
                CARDPIN,
                CARDNOTES,
                CARDEXPIRYDATE,
                CARDNAMEONCARD
        ))
);
```

Columns being defined like :-

```
static final DBColumn CARDID = new DBColumn(true);
static final DBColumn CARDOWNER = new DBColumn(
        CARDOWNER_COL,
        SQLINTEGER,
        false,
        "0"
);
static final DBColumn CARDNAME = new DBColumn(
        CARDNAME_COL,
        SQLTEXT,
        false,
        ""
);
static final DBColumn CARDTYPEREF = new DBColumn(
        CARDTYPEREF_COL,
        SQLINTEGER,
        false,
        "0"
);
```

Note! the first column CARDID, uses a shortcut constructor for standard _id columns.

To add a new column it's simply a matter of defining the DBColumn and including the DBColumn in the DBTable definition. The `onExpand` method will add the column via, in the case of a new column, the DBDatabase's `actionDBAlterSQL` method. New tables require the above plus the inclusion of the table in the DBDatabase definition and are applied by `onExpand` via the `actionDBBuildSQL` method.

`onExpand` is also called when the App(s) is started. However, with `true` being passed so that the `actionDBAlterSQL` method is called.

As an example adding :-

```
private static final String CARDCOLOUR_COL = "cardcolour";
..........
static final DBColumn CARDCOLOUR = new DBColumn(
        CARDCOLOUR_COL,
        SQLINTEGER,
        false,
        Long.toString(0x00_00_00_00_00L)
        // Flag, alpha, red, green, blue
        // Flag used to inidcate if colour has been set
);
```

and then adding `CARDCOLOUR` to the `DBTable` definition as per :-

```
static final DBTable CARDS = new DBTable(CARDS_TABLE,
        new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                CARDID,
                CARDOWNER,
                CARDNAME,
                CARDTYPEREF,
                CARDNUMBER,
                CARDCVVCODE,
                CARDPIN,
                CARDNOTES,
                CARDEXPIRYDATE,
                CARDNAMEONCARD,
                CARDCOLOUR     //<<<<<<<<<<
        ))
);
```

Results in (note logging exists when developing) :-

```
09-22 08:30:26.802 2713-2713/? D/DBEXPAND: Expanding Database Schema Usability=true
09-22 08:30:26.803 2713-2713/? D/DBEXPAND: Build SQL is as follows:-
09-22 08:30:26.803 2713-2713/? D/DBEXPAND: ALTERSQL is as folows:-
09-22 08:30:26.807 2713-2713/? D/DBEXPAND: ALterSQL Line=    ALTER TABLE cards ADD COLUMN cardcolour INTEGER  DEFAULT 0  ;
```

The resultant already populated table then looks like :-

[image]

Using `ALTER TABLE` with a `DEFAULT` value (*4th parameter of **DBColumn** (1st is column name, 2nd Type, 3rd true to include in primary index)*) populates the new column for existing rows.

Comment: How do you check whether the db is up to date or not?

Comment: Basically by comparing the pseudo schema against the real database via inspection of sqlite_master and PRAGMA. In addition to `onCreate` calling `onExpand`, `onExpand` is also called when starting the App(s) e.g. `DBHelper.getHelper(this).onExpand(mDBDAO.getDB(), true);`

Comment: @Anh-TuanMai previous comment explains (briefly). I've also updated the answer and also provided a real example.

Comment: @Anh-TuanMai PS if you want these they are at [Mike-j-t/Modules](https://github.com/Mike-j-t/Modules). They aren't bullet-proof but they certainly serve me. PS you'd likely want sqlwords as well as the 4 DB????.

Answer (score 1):

Check [**`onUpgrade`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int))

> Called when the database needs to be upgraded. The implementation
>   should use this method to drop tables, add tables, or do anything else
>   it needs to upgrade to the new schema version.

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion < 5) {
         db.execSQL("ALTER_TABLE_STATEMENT");
    }
    if (oldVersion < 6) {
         db.execSQL("ALTER_TABLE_STATEMENT2");
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear, since my database is up to date, `onUpgrade()` is not called. I want to trigger an action if my db is up to date. How can I do it better?

Comment: so, first , u have to check if DB is up to date? is it done?

Comment: beware of using `oldVersion == 5` etc. It is better to use `oldVersion < 5` in case a version is skipped. For example, if the user upgraded from V4 to V7, your intermediate Sql statements would not be called.

Comment: @Kuffs yes yes .

Answer (score 1):

You can set a flag inside your `onUpgrade` method of your `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

If the flag is not set by the time you get your reference to the OpenHelper then the database was already current and did not need updating.