# Android SQLite add new table on upgrade

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I would like to update my database and add a new table. So following [this Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133597/android-upgrading-db-version-and-adding-new-table) question, I have incremented my database from version 1 to version 2. Then in `onUpgrade`, I wrote the code to add new table and insert data:

```
@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (oldVersion < 2) {
            String CREATE_B_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS b ( " +
                    "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    "qset TEXT, "+
                    "highscore TEXT )";
            db.execSQL(CREATE_B_TABLE);

            String ADD_B = "INSERT INTO b ( qset ) VALUES ('1B'), ('2B'), ('3B'), ('4B'), ('5B'), ('6B'), ('7B'), ('8B'), ('9B'), ('10B')";
            db.execSQL(ADD_B);
        }
        this.onCreate(db);
    }
```

I also put the same code in `onCreate` to cater for new users.

However, something weird happened when the app is upgraded. The `Add_B` is inserted twice to the table, so I am having duplicated data. If I removed the code in `onUpgrade`, new table is added without duplication. It seem like `onCreate` is called when the app is upgraded, contradicting with the answer from another stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read correctly the code you are intentionally calling the onCreate method from your onUpgrade.

Just before the method ends you call: this.onCreate(db)

Comment: Thank you. What a silly mistake I made. I am trying to delete this question, but received warning from stackoverflow: "We do not recommend deleting questions with answers". Do you mind to delete your answer?

Comment: it won't let me delete it as well. Just "vote to delete it". I don't know how this voting system work.