# Upgrade an older SQLite database to the newer one. Android compatibility

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I recognized with using SQL-Queries ( instr() ) that I have an older SQlite database.
I am using the db for my android app.

How do I upgrade a SQlite-Database to a newer version outside of an android app ? With "outside" I mean that I prepare a database with my client ( pc ) not from android. 
I added the table android_metadata myself outside of my android app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424156/upgrade-sqlite-database-from-one-version-to-another

Comment: Copy your new database to <AppName>/AppName>/src/main/assets and then copy that database to application database folder or upgrade it.

Comment: Thanks @sqlab. This is a tutorial of howto upgrade it with a android app. Can I upgrade this outside the android app ? My ETL loads data from a JAVA-Application on my Client ( No Android ). Then I copy this DB to my Server. The Android App will download the DB and reads the content. So my question is, howto update my SQLite DB from outside an android app ?

Comment: Thanks @Zhora Khan. "or upgrade it". Thats the question :-)

Comment: It does not seem restricted to Android. You can transfer the solution to other  OSs too, if you write a program on your pc with bindings to SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

> I recognized with using SQL-Queries ( instr() ) that I have an older SQlite database.

This implies that you're in fact trying to upgrade the [library version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android). You cannot. It's really up to the device manufacturer to provide updates to platform libraries.

Upgrading the database file has nothing to do with updating the database library.

In theory you *could* compile the sqlite library on your own and distribute it with your app, or install a custom ROM for yourself with the updated library version. How to do it in practice is beyond the scope of this question.

If you have a problem the solution to which requires `instr()`, consider solving it some other way, possibly in Java code.